# docker-compose: zipkin cannot connect to elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, zipkin

I try to setup zipkin, elasticsearch, prometheus and grafana with docker-compose.yml 
When I run dockers, see in the log:

> dependencies_zipkin | 19/09/30 14:37:09 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [172.28.0.2:9200] failed (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)); no other nodes left - aborting...

I'm on MacOS X with docker 2.1.0.3

the content of my docker-compose.yml is this one:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  storage:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin-elasticsearch7
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    environment:
      - "xpack.security.enabled=false"
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    restart: unless-stopped
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - $PWD/prometheus:/etc/prometheus/
      - /tmp/prometheus:/prometheus/data:rw
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    restart: unless-stopped
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    depends_on: 
      - dependencies
      - storage
    environment: 
      - "STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch"
      - "ES_HOSTS=storage"
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    restart: unless-stopped
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped
  dependencies:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin-dependencies
    container_name: dependencies_zipkin
    depends_on: 
      - storage
    environment:
      - "STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch"
      - "ES_HOSTS=storage"
```

When I connect to localhost:9200, I see that elasticsearch is working fine and on port 9411, zipkin is deployed but I have the error:

> ERROR: cannot load service names: server error (Service Unavailable)(due to the network error

In the log, I have this information:

> 105 ^[[35mdependencies_zipkin |^[[0m 19/09/30 14:45:20 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [172.28.0.2:9200] failed (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)); no     other nodes left - aborting...

and this one

> ^[[31mzipkin          |^[[0m java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't connect any of [Endpoint{storage:80, ipAddr=172.28.0.2, weight=1000}]

Any idea?

UPDATE
by using mysql it is working fine, so the problem is at the level of elastic search.
I tried alsoo by using

> "STORAGE_PORT_9200_TCP_ADDR=127.0.0.1"

but the issue still occurs.

UPDATE
As mention is the solution gave by Brian, I have to use:

> ES_HOSTS=http://storage:9300

the key is on port, I was using the port 9200

The error disappear between zipkin and es but still occurs between es and zipkin-dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your `ES_HOSTS` variable, from the docs [here](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/844c43b9cde02b84583f0e3641fc20e670a3b25f/zipkin-server#elasticsearch-storage):

> - `ES_HOSTS`: A comma separated list of elasticsearch base urls to connect to ex. http://host:9200.
>               Defaults to "http://localhost:9200".

So you will need: `ES_HOSTS=http://storage:9200`

Comment: Hi. storage is the name of the service and I read somewhere in the documentation you can use the service name instead of url (storage is the name of the service not of the host). I tried http://localhost:9200, http://127.0.0.1:9200 but I still receive an error: dependencies_zipkin | 19/09/30 18:46:21 ERROR NetworkClient: Node [127.0.0.1:9200] failed (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused));. But thanks for your help

Comment: I apologize, you are totaly right but my mistake was to use the wrong http.port. 
the solution is : ES_HOSTS=http://storage:9300 and not 9200. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have this file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  storage:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin-elasticsearch7
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: zipkin
    environment: 
      - STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch
      - "ES_HOSTS=elasticsearch:9300"
    ports:
      - 9411:9411
    depends_on: 
      - storage

  dependencies:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin-dependencies
    container_name: dependencies
    entrypoint: crond -f
  depends_on:
    - storage
  environment:
    - STORAGE_TYPE=elasticsearch
    - "ES_HOSTS=elasticsearch:9300"
    - "ES_NODES_WAN_ONLY=true"

prometheus:
  image: prom/prometheus:latest
  container_name: prometheus
  volumes:
    - $PWD/prometheus:/etc/prometheus/
    - /tmp/prometheus:/prometheus/data:rw
  command:
    - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
    - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
    - '--web.console.libraries=/usr/share/prometheus/console_libraries'
    - '--web.console.templates=/usr/share/prometheus/consoles'
  ports:
    - "9090:9090"

grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana
  container_name: grafana
  depends_on:
    - prometheus
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

Main differences are the usage of

> "ES_HOSTS=elasticsearch:9300"

instead of

> "ES_HOSTS=storage:9300"

and in the dependencies configuration I add the entrypoint in dependencies:

> entrypoint: crond -f
>   This one is really the key to not have the exception when I start docker-compose.

To solve this issue, I check the this project: https://github.com/openzipkin/docker-zipkin

The remaining question is: why do I need to use entrypoint: crond -f